# R - Function of parentheses in functions

Tags: r, function, parentheses, magrittr

In was wondering what the function was of parentheses when passing one argument to a function via a pipe operator for example.

```
c(2,3) %>% max
```

or

```
c(2,3) %>% max()
```

Are there any consequences of not stating these parentheses? The outcome is the same.

Comment: I think they are exactly the same.

Comment: Stated in the detail section of  `?"%>%"`